# Create a dial effect with Excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a way to take a column of a small but arbitrary length and create a dial effect. I want to be able to shift a column down any amount, and then when the cells go over the set arbitrary amount for the cell contents to go back on top.

For illustration, see this picture of a dial lock. This is essentially what I'm trying to do:

[image: IMG:]

I'm trying to crack a crypt for a class and this would make it much easier.

It doesn't need to be in Excel. If there's a web app that can do that, it would be even better, however Excel has easy manipulation so it would be easiest to implement from scratch probably.

Comment: So are you looking for a function that simply rotates though the alphabet and goes back to A when it reaches Z, and for that function to be triggered by some sort of "shift amount" cell value? (Anyway, I'm sure there are plenty of Caesar cipher tools available online - why Excel? :) )

Comment: @NiayeshIsky Yes but it isn't the alphabet meaning the values can be alphanumeric, numbers, or letters in random order... I guess a Caesar cipher would've been a better analogy

Comment: If it is a Caesar cipher, even if it's alphanumeric, then [this decoder](https://www.dcode.fr/rot-cipher) may be easier and faster to use than making an Excel sheet (note that it has a ROT-18 function for alphanumeric ciphers).

Comment: @NiayeshIsky it isn't a standard set... for example, one 'alphabet' or excel column could be "IAGDIORRAESEMCGMIIEDEOANS". Then there are 3 other such strings of equal length and I want to be able to move them each individually, like you would a lock (see pic above)

Comment: Oh I see, you're describing a polyalphabetic cipher with changing character sets. That's doable in Excel, though a quick implementation won't be very pretty :)

Comment: It's kind of hypothetical question,, and my experience says it need programming or some built in tool, edit your post and add some related Tags to reach to larger audience !

Comment: If your goal is "trying to crack a crypt for a class".... then generate all possible combinations in excel and run your algo should do it just fine. But If your goal is to "Create a dial effect " you'll need to at least learn how to create an "up"  & "down" button using VBA to start this interface.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe how to do the dial effect like the lock, if you want to crack a code you should follow the advice of commenters.

The idea for this solution is to have your string of letters in one cell and each row of the dial will extract one letter with `MID`. `MOD` will be used to make the looping effect.

Insert the string of letters in the cell A1, the other cells of the first row will be used to get the position of each column of the dial.

Add spin buttons through the developer tab in the ribbon and link each one of them with one cell of the first row (you should have one for each column in your dial, I chose two in the example below).

In the first cell of the first dial column, put this formula :

`=MID($A$1,1+MOD(C$1+ROW()-ROW($C$2),LEN($A$1)),1)`

Then extend for as many columns as you want and as many rows as there are characters in A1.

How this works :

- `MID($A$1,<N>,1)` will extract the Nth character from cell A1
- `C$1+ROW()-ROW($C$2)` gets the position of the dial
- `1+MOD(<P>,LEN($A$1))` loops the position to the first one if it is greater than the length of the string in A1

[image: Example]